# “Unresolved Identifier” error SparkSetupMainController()” custom Particle Photon Swift iOS app (Standard Particle documentation procedure)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, particles, photon

**Hello there,**

I’m trying to connect my Particle Photon with a custom Swift iOS app. I’m writing code in Swift and use the official Particle iOS development documentation as my guidance. 
(https://docs.particle.io/guide/how-to-build-a-product/mobile-app/)

All the SDK’s are within my Xcode project and ready to be used. The SDK installation process via CocoaPods didn’t show any errors or ploblems.

I had to create an UIButton (startDeviceSetup) and added some code that (I think) asks for functions within Particle’s SDK.

Code given by Particle in their documentation:

> @IBAction func startDeviceSetup(sender: AnyObject) {
>       var setupController = SparkSetupMainController()
>       self.presentViewController(setupController, animated: true, completion: nil)
>   }

After creating and connecting my UIButton and entering the following code. Xcode gives me an Unresolved Identifier error when I’m trying to make a build:

[Unresolved Identifier error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k5yE.png)

The internet tells me that “Unresolved Identifier” seems to be a common error that often have something to do with Target memberships or classes that aren’t public. Unfortunately I can’t figure out the location of my problem. I strictly followed Particles documentation and did nothing different.

**Additional information**

I’m using Xcode 8.0, iOS 10 and Swift 3. I installed Particles SDK’s using CocoaPods. As described in the official Particle documentation. I created a new UIButton within my main.storyboard and connected it as an action to my ViewController etc.

Also Imports like this “import Spark-SDK” didn't make any difference.

Thank you for reading my question,
I’m still searching for an answer. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me :)

Comment: Where did you import it? `Also Imports like this “import Spark-SDK” didn't make any difference.`

Comment: I imported it to my ViewController.swift.

Comment: did you run `pod install`?

Comment: @Santosh Uhm yes I did, all the files and folders created by "pod install" are within my project navigator. Folders like: SpartSetup, Spark-SDK, AFNetworking etc.  Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/IO9c6

Comment: Yes! Somehow Xcode fixed itself. I just reinstalled Xcode. Importing Spark-SDK and SparkSetup works fine now. Thanks anyway @Santosh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow Xcode fixed itself. I just reinstalled it. Importing Spark-SDK and SparkSetup in my ViewController works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bridge from your swift project to pods file. In other word you need to create a header file